# How can I add my credentials into .gitignore but still execute my python?

Tags: python, json, git, lambda, config

I am confused on how to add my credentials to .gitignore when they are in my config file. I have database credentials stored in my config file and they are used to execute my code below:

```
import os 
import json
import platform
import logging
import pymysql as pm
import boto3

class ClassName:
    env=None
    config=None

    def __init__(self, env_filename):
        self.env=env_filename
        self.config=self.get_config()

    def get_config(self):
        with open(self.env) as file_in:
            return json.load(file_in)
        
    def is_Windows():
        if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def DB_connection(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        connection = None
        try:
            config=ClassName.get_config(self)
            host=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["host"]
            port=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["port"]
            database=config["exceptions"]["database-secrets"]["db"]

            # retrieve DB password from secrets manager by invoking exceptions lambda function
            dbUserName = "user"
            lambdaFunctionName = "exceptions"
            client = boto3.client('lambda')
            response = client.invoke(FunctionName=lambdaFunctionName)
            result = json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode())
            dbPassword = result["pass"]

            connection = pm.connect(user=dbUserName,password=dbPassword,host=host,port=port,database=database)
    
            logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))
        
        return connection
    

    def run_all(self):
        def func1(self):
            func1_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func1_Exceptions();"
            vfcaa = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["func1"]
            if vfcaa:
                with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                    with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                        try:
                            cur.execute(func1_INSERT_QUERY)
                            print("func1 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                            cur.execute(func1_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                            print("func1 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                            data=cur.fetchall()                     
                            for row in data:
                                for col in row:
                                    print (col, end=' ')
                                print('\n')

                        except pm.Error as e:
                            print(f"Error: {e}")

                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.exception(e)

                        else:
                            cnxn.commit()
        func1(self)

        def func2(self):
            func2_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func2_Exceptions();"
            vfj = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["func2"]
            if vfj:
                with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                    with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                        try:
                            cur.execute(func2_INSERT_QUERY)
                            print("func2 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                            cur.execute(func2_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                            print("func2 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                            data=cur.fetchall()                     
                            for row in data:
                                for col in row:
                                    print (col, end=' ')
                                print('\n')

                        except pm.Error as e:
                            print(f"Error: {e}")

                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.exception(e)

                        else:
                            cnxn.commit()
        func2(self)

        def func3(self):
            func3_INSERT_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Insert_Daily_Records();"
            func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY = "CALL sp_func3_Exceptions();"
            vfl = self.config["verafin-exceptions"]["functions"]["func3"]
            if vfl:
                with self.DB_connection() as cnxn:
                    with cnxn.cursor() as cur:
                        try:
                            cur.execute(func3_INSERT_QUERY)
                            print("func3 insertion query ran successfully, {} records updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')

                            cur.execute(func3_EXCEPTIONS_QUERY)
                            print("func3 exceptions query ran successfully, {} exceptions updated.".format(cur.rowcount), '\n')
                            data=cur.fetchall()                   
                            for row in data:
                                for col in row:
                                    print (col, end=' ')
                                print('\n')

                        except pm.Error as e:
                            print(f"Error: {e}")

                        except Exception as e:
                            logging.exception(e)

                        else:
                            cnxn.commit()
        func3(self)

def main():
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    if "win" in (platform.system().lower()):
        vfc=(cwd+"\config"+".json")
    else:
        vfc=(cwd+"/config"+".json")
    ve=ClassName(vfc)
    ve.run_all()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My config has info stored here in json format:

```
{
    "exceptions":{
        "database-secrets":{
            "host": "host",
            "db": "db",
            "port": port
        },
        "functions":{
            "func1": true,
            "func2": true,
            "func3": true
        }
    }
}
```

I have to add them into .gitignore because the credentials will differ depending on the levels.

Comment: What deployment problem do you have?

Comment: Why cant you store your credentials in .env file and  add to .gitignore file. python-dotenv module is designed to address the same problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can add your config file to `.gitignore` and then once you deploy your app in the server, you can manually add a new config file in the server to get it working.

This way your credentials are not exposed in your git repo.
This is a pretty standard procedure which many people use, but nowadays its better managed by third party services such as Azure KeyVault etc. You could take a look into that.

Comment: i guess how do i add my config file to .gitignore? i want to use this approach. do i copy&past what I have in my config into .gitignore? i am not sure how to do this.

Comment: it's confusing because my main python script uses my config file to read in the credentials so if i get rid of my config, it wont read it

Comment: `.gitignore` file contains the path to all the files that you need git to ignore. 

So you have to add the path to your config file in `.gitignore`

Once you have added it in, git will start to ignore your config file during commits, pushes etc. You can then add the config file manually in your server as well as your local development machine.

Comment: OH OK now i get it. ill add the path to my config there. yes it was resolved, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You could just not push the credentials to git. During the deployment, you can inject this credential file into the file system and reference it in the code as usual.

maybe you could consider using a solution like https://www.vaultproject.io/ as well